# Python: input a number and return whether its odd or even

Tags: python, if-statement

Every time I use the if statement directly after using input I get an error. For example:

```
num = input("Enter a number: ")
if num % 2 == 0:
  print("Even Number")
else:
  print("Odd Number")
```

I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2, in 
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `input` returns a string in Python 3 and Python thinks you're try to format with `%` here. You should convert to a numeric type

Answer (score 4):

You are using Python 3, where `input` returns a string. Convert your input to an integer with `int(input("Enter a number: "))`.

Answer (score 2):

Input returns a string. You must typecast to an int.

`num = int(input("Enter a number: " )`

or

`if int(num) % 2 == 0:`